# Is there any jquery countdown analog clock

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

When someone click a button on my page, I want to display a countdown analog clock. The countdown analog clock may look like:

[image]

I have searched in Google but not found anything related, I want to ask is there any jquery countdown analog clock plugin that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: You could just... write one yourself. You know, if the guy who created jQuery just looked for ready-made code, he wouldn't be making ready-made code for other people who look for ready-made code. Or something. I did have a point there, somewhere...

Comment: Search Google for "jQuery analog clock", then reverse the code to count down instead of up.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the page. Hope it helps. http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-cool-jquery-clock-tutorials-analog-digital/